# LiveDataContext.SignIn

Tags: asp.net, windows-live-id, windows-live

Am I correct in understanding that the Method LiveDataContext.SignIn can only be used in Windows Applications?

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff747817.aspx

I tried to implement it in ASP.NET but get an error that I cannot use Modal Windows. So it seems to me that SignIn uses the Windows.Forms.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty independent of mvc or webforms I think.

Windows Live Messenger Connect Developer Guide
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243641.aspx